# how to get value from a datalist and save into @Html.HiddenFor mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, html-datalist

I need get value from a datalist and save into `@Html.HiddenFor`

Below are my details:

```
<datalist id="list">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Per)
{
    <option id="@item.Value" value="@item.Text">@item.Text</option>
}
</datalist>
@Html.HiddenFor = datalist item
```

regards

Comment: You need to create hidden field when you render razor page or on client side? I mean what whould be in HiddenFor? Selected value?

Comment: Lol you guys playing chinese whispers with the edits, "details" was originally "datalist".

Comment: @Sippy lol, but actually this kind looks cleaner =)

Answer (score 2):

In your view:

`@Html.Hidden("datalistSelected")`

Then use JS/JQuery to assign a value when an option is selected in your datalist:

```
$('#inputID').bind("input", function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#datalistSelected').val(value);
})
```

You can then submit to your controller action by having it accept `datalistSelected` as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult DatalistSelected(string datalistSelected) {
    ....
}
```

Or by having your controller accept the view model when you post from the view, or again alternatively by having a custom model binder convert your view model back to a domain model and having your action accept the domain model as a parameter.